# If $f(x) = \int_{\cos x}^0 \tan(t)\mathrm dt$, what is $f'(x)$?

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

If $f(x) = \int_{\cos x}^0 \tan(t)\mathrm dt$, what is $f'(x)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int^0_{\cos(x)}\tan(t)dt\\
&=-\int_0^{\cos(x)}\tan(t)dt\\
f'(x) & = -\dfrac{d}{d\cos(x)}\int_0^{\cos(x)}\tan(t)dt\ \cdot\dfrac{d\cos(x)}{dx}\\
&= \sin(x)\cdot\tan(\cos(x))
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Use the rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(\int_a^x{f(t)dt})=f(x)$$
And the composition rule.

Let $f(x)=\int_{\cos x}^0{\tan t dt}=-h(\cos x)$ where $h(x)=\int_0^{x}{\tan t dt}$

So, $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-h'(\cos x).(\cos x)'=\sin x.\tan(\cos x)$

Comment: Why are you giving a detailed answer, when the author made no attempt whatsoever? You are probably doing his/her homework. You can ask them to show their work first, or give a hint.

Comment: @Fareed AF. Please invert the limits ( according to the question)

Comment: Your right about that @A.Pongrácz I'll do pay attention to that ...